# <AS- Java> Floating Activity: Always Centered

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a floating activity that overlays over the users screen: this overlay is always centered and I cannot fathom why.

In my XML I have:

> ```
> <style name="PopupTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
>     <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
>     <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
>     <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
>     <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
>     <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
>     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
>     <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
>     <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
>     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
>     <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
>     <item name="android:gravity">bottom</item>
>     <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
> </style>
> ```

As you can see, Gravity has no effect on the style: I also tried the alignment tags and that didn't work either.

Next we have my onCreate Method, and although it wasn't required I added the requestWindowFeature() just incase I needed to declare it to gain access to edit the default settings:

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
>     params.y = 80;
>     getWindow().setAttributes(params);
>     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);        
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     }
> ```

Finally (well it was actually first) I have my override method:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onAttachedToWindow() {
>     DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
>     WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)  getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.WINDOW_SERVICE); // the results will be higher than using the activity context object or the getWindowManager() shortcut
>     wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
>     int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
>     int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;        
>     WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
>     params.y = 80;
>     this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
>     this.getWindow().setLayout(screenWidth, screenHeight /2);
>     }
> ```

(btw the setLayout works fine, and has adjusted the screen perfectly fine: which just adds the confusion) The params.y = 80; where 80 means align y to bottom.

All this floating activity needs to do it just sit at the bottom of the device and take up half the space of the screen. Yet it insists on being centered constantly.

All the best,
Antony

Answer (score 0):

For people who came here for the same problem: it was the params.y = 80 in the override method. It needed to be 8388611 - although this doesn't make sense, as it's a value of the params.x: either way, just make sure you do the setAttributes after!